# Unable to modify the "To Do" hrs for the accepted user stories in Rally

Tags: rally

There are few accepted user stories from the previous sprints, I can see some TO DO hrs but when I looked into tasks defined for the user stories all the tasks TO DO showing as Zero.

If try yo modify the user story.. It is showing 'TO DO' hrs but showing in disable mode. I can't edit it.

Is there any why to modify the 'To Do'? Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of the context ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly modify ToDo on a story.

[Per documentation](https://help.rallydev.com/creating-user-story):

To Do: The automatic calculation or roll up of to do estimates for all tasks per user story.

You may try this sequence of steps:
Create a story.
Crate a task. It's state is Defined.
Set Task's Estimate to 2 h. ToDo is automatically set to 2 h.
This task's ToDo value rolls up to the story. Now ToDo on a story is 2 h.
Set the state of the task to Complete.
ToDo automatically changes to 0.0.
This value rolls up to the story.